# I was installing the python for the first time, but I can't access the check box for admin privileges, it doesn't allow to check or uncheck it

Tags: checkbox, installation, download, admin, privileges

I was installing the python for the first time but I can't access the check box for admin privileges, please help.

The check box is marked in grey and doesn't allow to check or uncheck it.

Wanted to check the box for admin privileges